# QFileDialog not opening from Dialog window, but it does open from MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I'm trying to open the file explorer dialog from a dialog window using Qt and C++. My "dialog.cpp" file looks like this:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "QFileDialog"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_Browse_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "C://", "All files (*.*)");
}
```

Everywhere I have looked says that this should work without a problem. So I tried putting the same exact code in my "mainwindow.cpp" file. Which is this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "QFileDialog"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Open_dialog_clicked()
{
    dialogUi.setupUi(dialog);
    dialog->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Save_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "C://", "All Files (*.*)");
}
```

This opens up the file explorer dialog with no issues. However, I want to open the file explorer from the dialog window that is opened by the main window, which isn't working even though it's the same exact code. I even added a new MainWindow class ("mainwindow2.cpp") and tried from that to see if maybe it was the Dialog class causing an issue, but the file explorer wouldn't open from that either. It only seems to work from the primary MainWindow class. (By this I mean any window opened from "mainwindow.cpp" cannot open a file explorer dialog, but "mainwindow.cpp" can open the explorer)

Comment: Working for me in Qdialog. tested now. Could you please post your signa/slot connection line

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Qt and am not sure what this means.

Comment: Something like this: QObject::connect(YOURBUTTONOBJECT, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_Browse_clicked()));

Comment: @pavanc Seeing the name that has the format `on_{name}_clicked()`, you can assume that you have created the connection with the help of `QDesigner`.

Comment: @SeanGaffney I have tried your code and I have not had problems, as you are new using Qt you could try to create a new project and see if the problem still exists.